# С чем едят тэг <merge>

Tags: java, android, xml

Наткнулся на [статью](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) 2009 года, где приводятся рекоммендации к использованию тега `<merge>` при создании разметки, так и не понял как его можно использовать. Почитал на английском, но не разобрался, может кто то сможет на родном, могучем разъяснить?

p.s. с тэгом `<include>` разобрался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тэг  нередко позволяет избавиться от лишнего уровня вложенности контейнеров. Чтобы было понятнее, опишу один из распространённых кейсов использования этого тэга.

Допустим, вы решили сделать кастомную вьюху: создали соответствующий класс, после чего, унаследовали его от LinearLayout (или RelativeLayout, не имеет особого значения). Важно понимать, что с этого момента у вас уже есть корневой контейнер, соответствующий типу Layout, от которого унаследован класс вашей вьюхи. Если класс вью унаследован от LinearLayout, вся вёрстка, которую вы пропишете в XML ляжет в контейнер LinearLayout и будет располагаться там согласно принципам LinearLayout, хотя в самом XML этот контейнер нигде прописан у вас не будет.

Когда вы приступите к вёрстке дизайна, вы столкнётесь с необходимостью создать общий контейнер для всех ваших элементов (если их там будет несколько). Допустим, вам надо в эту вьюху положить две кнопки. Вы, скорее всего, обернёте их в LinearLayout, потому что IDE просто не даст вам положить два элемента в корень XML.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Но тогда получается, что прописанный в XML LinearLayout, ляжет в LinearLayout, от которого унаследован класс вашей вьюхи - и получается излишняя и совершенно никому ненужная вложенность. Иерархия элементов интерфейса будет выглядеть примерно так:

- LinearLayout

  - LinearLayout

    - Button
    - Button

Именно чтобы избавиться от этого лишнего LinearLayout и используется тэг . Вы просто оборачиваете в него все элементы в XML. При этом друг относительно друга элементы будут располагаться как в LinearLayout, так как по сути вы кладёте их в него.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</merge>
```

Теперь иерархия элементов будет выглядеть так:

- LinearLayout

  - Button
  - Button

Каков смысл всего этого? Да, один вложенный контейнер погоды не сделает и вряд ли отобразится на быстродействии вашего приложения, но если можно упростить структуру, почему бы не сделать этого? К минусам использования тэга  относится то, что с отредактировать параметры контейнера в XML уже возможности не будет. Придётся задавать отступы, фоны и т.д. программно.